# Implementing Delete for Typing Text using example

Tags: javascript, html

I came across this script in W3 schools for Typing Text. Try as a might, I can't implement a delete function so the user sees text, deletes then 're types. I'm trying to avoid jQuery. Is it also possible to add the text in the html part instead of using a variable?

```js
var i = 0;
var txt = 'Lorem ipsum typing effect!'; /* The text */
var speed = 50; /* The speed/duration of the effect in milliseconds */

function typeWriter() {
  if (i < txt.length) {
     document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML += 
     txt.charAt(i);
     i++;
     setTimeout(typeWriter, speed);
   }
 }
```

```html
<p id="demo"></p>
```

Comment: You haven't posted any of the code of your attempted delete functions, what sort of output are you looking for? Type text, delete it, then type it again, or what?

Comment: You can't really do

Comment: you can read the phrase on demo para tag, remove the last character and then replace it back. Use document.getElementById("demo").value to read phrase and remove last character and replace the value again using document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML

Comment: Thank you for all of your replies.Yes I would like it to type, then delete a word, then type again. For example, type, lorem ipsum typing, then delete typing and add example. I have tried to use a while loop instead of the if statement but it doesnt work, for example 'while (i < 28 //(character I want to delete up to) 'then use 'document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML -= 
     txt.charAt(i); //(minus instead of +)' but no luck.